# How to check POST request in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Is there a way to check if it was a POST request in Grails,  I mean like we do in PHP (if (isset($_POST))). I need it for form submission code in the same controller action which renders a form.

```
def myform {
  if (POST) {
     myModel.save
  }
  render view: myView, model: [user: myModel]
}
```

I cannot use params, because there are always some parameters and it's not empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do `if(request.method == 'POST')`

Comment: No, I meant not to determine the type of request, but check if it is empty or not. Does it contain any POST data or not.

Comment: Of course, may be that is enough, if request is POST than it is a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

In a Grails controller you have access to `request` which is an [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). Using the `getMethod()` method you should be able to do something like this:

`if (request.getMethod().equals('POST'))`